# Python Json TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, mysql, json, database

i'm new in json. i'm work with mysql and json in my python project. i have json file like this:

[image]

i want to store some contents to sql database, but i have an error `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting` when i run the code. Here's the piece of code:

```
def create_db(db_name, table_name):
    # try:
    db = dbconnect()
    cursor = db.cursor()

    cursor.execute("SET sql_notes = 0;")

    cursor.execute("CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS {}".format(db_name))

    cursor.execute("SET sql_notes = 0;")

    cursor.execute(
        """CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS {}.{}(waktu varchar(150),plate varchar(20),region varchar(150), score varchar(20), filename varchar(50));""".format(db_name, table_name))

    cursor.execute("SET sql_notes = 1;")

    with open('data.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for i in data:
        cursor.execute(
            """INSERT INTO {}.{}(waktu, plate, region, score, filename) VALUES(%s,%s)""".format
            (db_name, table_name),
            (i['timestamp'], i['results'][0]['plate'], i['results'][0]['region']['code'], i['results'][0]['score'], i['filename']))

    db.commit()
    db.close()

    # except Exception as e:
    #     print(e)

create_db(db_name="plate_recognizer", table_name="kendaraan")
```

how to solve this? any helps will be appriciate, thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is here:

```py
 """INSERT INTO {}.{}(waktu, plate, region, score, filename) VALUES(%s,%s)""".format
            (db_name, table_name),
            (i['timestamp'], i['results'][0]['plate'], i['results'][0]['region']['code'], i['results'][0]['score'], i['filename']))
```

You provided 5 arguments(`(i['timestamp'], i['results'][0]['plate'], i['results'][0]['region']['code'], i['results'][0]['score'], i['filename']))`) but only has 2 formats(`VALUES(%s,%s)`). You should add more formats like this: `VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s)`(use proper format if needed).